# Terminology of sets of outcomes

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, terminology

When you speak of sets of outcomes you differentiate between the set of outcomes called the 'sample space' and the set of outcomes you get after you repeat an experiment some n times.

Since probabilities refer to fractions of that second set and expected values refer to it as well, I find myself having to mention that second set a lot. Is there a name for it?
Right now, I use the phrase 'experiment space' which is terrible.

Comment: By 'the second set' do you mean the set of all events? Or a subset of the set of all events?<br/><br/>
I am not yet sure about any name but this is how we refer to it:<br/>
$Ω$ denotes the sample space and $F$ denote the set of all events.<br/><br/>
So, basically we have assigned an alphabet/special symbol to that second set and always refer to it by that instead of using a specific name.
<br/><br/>
Sorry if it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I meant the set of repetitions of an experiment. I guess there is no particular name for it from what I can see. I could swear I saw somewhere the phrase 'empirical set' or 'empirical space'.